# Call function at any time on input, python 3.x

Tags: python, python-3.x, function

If you made a function like this:

```
def show():
    print(something)
```

How would you make it so that, on any input, if the user typed a specific thing, this would be called? I want multiple functions like this to be able to be called whenever the user wants. Would I just have to have it as an option every time I ask for an input?

EDIT: sorry, this wasn't very clear. Say I have a variable in a game, like money. When I ask for an input as the game goes along, the inputs being about unrelated things, I want the user to be able to type eg. gold and the show() function will activate. Then the input will go on as usual. Would I be able to do this without just have it as an option for each input, eg.

```
variable = input("type something")
if variable == "gold":
    do stuff
elif variable == other things
    do other things
```

Comment: Write a function that takes input, checks it against something and then prints something if necessary? Not quite sure what your question is here...

Comment: Yes... so - put your code there into its own function and call that when you need it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you mean something like this:

```
def thing1(): # Random command
    print('stuff')
def thing2(): # Random command
    print('More stuff')


def check(command):
    '''Checks if the users command is valid else it does a default command'''
    if command == 'thing1':
        thing1()
    elif command == 'thing2':
        thing2()
    else:
        default_thing()

while True: # Loop going on forever
    userinput = input('') # Lets the user input their command
    check(userinput)
```

Answer (score 0):

you could put all your functions in a dictionary: `{"<some user input>":func_to_call}` and see if it matches any

something like:

```
def gold():
    print("gold")

input_options = {"gold":gold}

variable = input("type something:")
if variable in input_options:
    input_options[variable]()
```

Comment: you could automate this even more by using a decorator to register `gold()` automatically